# 1-to-1 correspondence between pin$^−$ structure and spin structure

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, geometric-topology

> "There is 1-to-1 correspondence between pin$^−$ structures on a vector bundle V and spin structures on V ⊕ det V."

- In which context, is this relation between pin$^−$ structure and spin structure true? How to show the above is true?
- Is the  det V (of the vector bundle V) a determinant bundle that always has to be a determinant line bundle? (are there any kinds of determinant line bundle which are not determinant line bundle? )

Comment: The determinant of a vector bundle always refers to its top exterior power $\bigwedge^{\operatorname{rk} V} V$, which is a line bundle. It sounds like what you might be asking about are the other exterior powers $\bigwedge^{k} V$ for $1 < k < \operatorname{rk} V$, which are always vector bundles of rank $>1$.

Comment: As for your question about spin structures, I would suggest providing additional context and indicating where you got this statement from.

Comment: thanks - let me try another one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3945153/141334

Comment: You've already asked about the fact about spin structures [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3895484), and you've even provided a [reference](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kirbytaylorpin.pdf).  I also gave a separate perspective on how such a result can be proved in that post.